# Formula for the complement of the Cantor set

Tags: general-topology

According to the wikipedia article:
$$C=[0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=0}^{3^{m-1}-1} \left(\frac{3k+1}{3^m},\frac{3k+2}{3^m}\right)$$
"Let us note that this description of the Cantor set does not characterize the complement of the Cantor set exactly, since the sets given by the formula
$$\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=0}^{3^{m-1}-1} \left(\frac{3k+1}{3^m},\frac{3k+2}{3^m}\right)$$
are not disjoint."

My question is this:

> Which sets in particular are not disjoint?

I've tried to understand it but it seems to me that they are disjoint no matter how I look at it.

Comment: The sets defined for $m=1$ and $m=2$, for instance, are not disjoint. Still, what wikipedia wrote does not quite make sense: Describing the complement has nothing to do with disjointness. (The word "characterize" is very much unclear.)

Comment: @studiosus Well, they probably refer to the theorem that every open set in the reals (so also the complement of the Cantor set) can be written unique as a disjoint union of open (possibly unbounded) intervals. They "warn" that this union is not that representation.

Comment: @studiosus Ahh I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @studiosus said

> The sets defined for m=1 and m=2, for instance, are not disjoint. Still, what wikipedia wrote does not quite make sense: Describing the complement has nothing to do with disjointness. (The word "characterize" is very much unclear.)

This post is community wiki in order to "answer" this question.